# Why aren't these two random processes the same? How can I extend it to higher length arrays?

Tags: random-variables, random, python

I want to create a random array of probabilities (all combinations equality likely). In the case of an array of length two, I can do the following (code in Python):

```
results = []
for _ in range(100000):
    results.append(np.random.random())
print(np.mean(results), np.std(results))
Output: 0.5010405458900358 0.2889116594183084
```

In this particular case, the variable assigned to the 1st element of the array has average 0.5 and standard deviation of around 0.288. I can assign the random number to the 2nd element of the array just by doing `1 - 1st` (drawn from random uniform distribution).

However, I don't know how to do it for arrays of higher lengths. I tried to draw random numbers from a uniform distribution (same size as length of array) and divide by its sum. But that doesn't work. An example:

```
results = []
for _ in range(100000):
    arr = np.random.random(2)
    results.append(arr[0] / np.sum(arr))
print(np.mean(results, axis=0), np.std(results, axis=0))
Output: 0.49934817136203025 0.23833927694747173
```

Clearly, the two codes are not equivalent. Why? Why is that in the 2nd case, the standard deviation is lower than the first? (maybe the summation of two random uniform variables alter the distribution). But how can I extend the first case (first code example) to higher lengths?

Thank you everyone.

Comment: I only append arr[0] in 2nd example.

Comment: If I want two create an array of two random probabilities, I can draw a random number from a uniform distribution. That random number will be my probability of element 1 in the array. The probability of element 2 in the array can be computed by 1-random_number. But what about for an array with length 3 (4, 5, etc)?

Comment: I thought of creating a random array and dividing by its sum (to normalize it), but it doesn't give the same result, as I stated in the post.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/354278/generating-a-random-probability-vector

Comment: That's it. Many thanks for the link.

Comment: Yes. It does answer my question.